# Postgres - What column type to use to store nested arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

In my nodeJs application I need to store and retrieve nested arrays that represents coordinates of features geometry (point, lines, polygon) but not in a format usually used by postgis.

For instance the arrays would look like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, ...], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, ...], ...]
```

or conceptually:

```
[[x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, ...], [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, ...], ...]
```

I dont want to transform those arrays into a postgis geom structure.

I want to be able to store and retrieve thoses arrays in the simplest way.

What postgres column type would you suggest?

**Edit: those arrays could be large**

**Edit2: In the example above, the numbers are small int but in reality they would be float**

Comment: longtext, but convert your array to json prior to storing it, and unconvert it on retrieval

Comment: What would be the actual range and type of the numbers? Simple small integers like demonstrated or something else, really? Would all nested arrays strictly share the same number of elements?

Comment: Just use `YouType[][]`, it's easy to search through and process within Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter in fact the numbers would be float

Comment: You missed my 2nd (important) question. Postgres arrays require matching length for all array dimensions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter No lengths would variate between arrays and nested arrays

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: Length can vary between levels, but all arrays of one level have to have the same number of elements. Is that the case? Like this in not possible: `'{{1,2,3},{1,2}}'`. (One could fill in NULL values for minor deviations ...)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter correct, lengths of one level will vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text`.

Really, if you're not going to manipulate them in the database (eg search by coordinates) `text` will be smaller (and compress better), and easier to work with than either `json`/`jsonb` or SQL arrays (which can be multidimensional, just for the record).